# Execute a function after particular time in NodeJs and its lifetime

Tags: node.js, timer

In my node application with mongodb I have feature where users can post books on rent and other users can request for them with a "whenDate". One post is mapped to only one book.

Consider a user requests for a book for 1 week 5 days from now. In this case I want to lock the book for a week so that no one else can request at that period.

1) How can I achieve in NodeJs that a function gets executed after sometime considering that I will be having many of them? This function will get executed after 5 days in the above case to lock the particular book document. Please consider the question 2 also.

2) I don't want these timers to get deleted if I restart my application. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TTL feature in mongo DB to discard records automatically after the time to live.

Let's say you keep a table with the booking requests and set TTL according to the booking duration. Mongo DB then can remove these booking record after the TTL is achieved. So your node.js application does not need to trigger any job.

Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: I know about TTL in mongodb. But as you see my requirement is not to delete the document but to update it and I also want to send push notifications at that particular time.

Comment: Ok. In that case, I suggest you create a separate collection for the requests to rent so that you would not actually delete the actual book record. Would that work?

Comment: That would not solve my purpose. What I want is something very specific to node js. For every booking I want a function that will get triggered automatically when the booking period starts.